# alternatives to gmail usage for django password reset

Tags: django

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = "587"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "myemail"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "mypassword"
```

i am trying to implement django password reset, but i need to create app password in gmail which requires two-step verification which is not allowed by google in my country Nigeria

what alternative do i have so i can implement django password reset?

Answer (score 1):

- SendGrid ([Docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/django/) to setup for Django, I have used this one)
- MailGun

You can get plenty more by searching around yourself.

Django also has libraries that will do the work for you, some examples are,

- django-anymail
- django-mailer
- django-templated-email